# How to add Octave to PATH environment variable in Mac Sierra?

Tags: macos, path, octave

I'm wondering whether someone couald tell me how to add Octave to PATH environment variable in Mac Sierra?

I need to make available octave under terminal from any folder.

I have installed my last version of octave in my machine but... what's now?
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your `~/.bash_profile` file and add your Octave installation folder (note that yours may be different than mine) to the `PATH` environment variable.

**`~/.bash_profile`**

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/octave/4.2.0/bin"
```

Note that this modified `PATH` environment variable will only be available from the terminal (not GUI apps).

Comment: Dear Suever, thanks a lot. But I have tryed to finf out my octave in usr/local, but it doesnt. Ill try to setting it up again and see where the H is installed!

Comment: @Gohann What method did you use to install it?