# How do you run Octave in Jupyter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, octave, jupyter-lab, octave-gui

I want to run Octave in JupyterLab on a M1 Macbook. I have installed JupyterLab using `pip` and `Octave-6.3.0-beta1.dmg` file as per the prerequisites.

I have also installed Octave kernel using `pip install octave_kernel --user`. 
 Now I am somewhat stuck. This [documentation](https://github.com/Calysto/octave_kernel) says, 
 *"We require the `Octave` executable to run the kernel. Add that executable's directory to the `PATH` environment  variable or use the `OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE` to point to the executable itself."* 
 Can someone help me with this? What am I supposed to type in the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

`PATH` is an ["environment variable"](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them). It basically makes anything that runs in your computer know few software and their location. That way, when you do e.g. `python my_code.py` it knows what `python` is.

Read the link above too to learn how to add stuff to `PATH`, in your case, the location of Octave. The location should be something like `C:\Octave\Octave-5.1.0.0\mingw64\bin`, where the folder contains `octave.bat`, for a windows machine. Just find wherever Octave is in you MAC.

There is another similar question about this: [How to add Octave to PATH environment variable in Mac Sierra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41512062/how-to-add-octave-to-path-environment-variable-in-mac-sierra)